# Why does uint64_t value change when it is being assigned into unit64_t** array element?

Tags: c, pointers, uint64

I am trying to simulate a memory manager in C language. I need help solving a problem with assigning `uint64_t` values into an `uint64_t**` array elements.

After writing the code, I tested it by trying to write several values.

ex:- 0x2222222222222222, 0x33, 0x11111111 ....

This is my complete code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct Memory{
    int hashtablesize;
    uint32_t **hashtable; // The array address in use 
    uint64_t **values; // Stored values


    void (*write)(uint32_t *address, struct Data *data, struct Memory *mem);

    void (*read)(uint32_t *address, struct Data *data, struct Memory *mem);

    int (*cell_index)(uint32_t *address, struct Memory *mem);

    void (*extend_hashtable)(struct Memory *mem);

    void (*dump)(struct Memory *mem);

};

struct Data{
    enum Type {UINT8,UINT16,UINT32,UINT64} type;
    uint64_t* value;
};


void write(uint32_t *address, struct Data *data, struct Memory *mem){

    int cell_index = mem->cell_index(address,mem);

    if(data->type==UINT8){
        uint64_t value = *((uint64_t*)data->value) & 0x00000000000000FF;
        mem->values[cell_index]=value;
    }
    if(data->type==UINT16){
        uint64_t value = *((uint64_t*)data->value) & 0x000000000000FFFF;
        mem->values[cell_index]=value;
    }
    if(data->type==UINT32){
        uint64_t value = *((uint64_t*)data->value) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
        mem->values[cell_index]=value;
    }
    if(data->type==UINT64){
        uint64_t value = *((uint64_t*)data->value) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        mem->values[cell_index]=value;
    }
    
    mem->hashtable[cell_index]=*address;
}

//void read(uint32_t *address, struct Data *data, struct Memory *mem){

    // To be implemented

//}


// Return the index of the given address from **hashtable
int cell_index(uint32_t *address, struct Memory *mem){
    int hashtablesize = mem->hashtablesize;

    for(int i;i<hashtablesize;i++){
        if(mem->hashtable[i]==*address){
            return i;
        }
    }
    mem->extend_hashtable(mem);

    return mem->hashtablesize-1;
}


// This function dynamically allocate memory for new memory addresses
void extend_hashtable(struct Memory *mem){
    int hashtablesize = mem->hashtablesize;

    uint32_t **new_hashtable = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t*)*(hashtablesize+1));
    uint64_t **new_values = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t*)*(hashtablesize+1));

    memset(new_hashtable, 0, (hashtablesize+1) * sizeof(uint32_t*));
    memset(new_values, 0, (hashtablesize+1) * sizeof(uint64_t*));

    for(int i;i<hashtablesize;i++){
        new_hashtable[i] = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(new_hashtable[i], 0, sizeof(uint32_t));
        new_hashtable[i] = mem->hashtable[i];
    }

    for(int i;i<hashtablesize;i++){
        new_values[i] = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
        memset(new_values[i], 0, sizeof(uint64_t));
        new_values[i] = mem->values[i];
    }

    mem->hashtable = new_hashtable;
    mem->hashtablesize+=1;
    mem->values = new_values;

}


// Print out the addresses and store values
void dump(struct Memory *mem){
    int hashtablesize = mem->hashtablesize;

    for(int i;i<hashtablesize;i++){
        printf("Memory Address: %x, \t Value: %u\n",mem->hashtable[i],mem->values[i]);
    }
    printf("Memory dump success\n");
}
```

In the `dump` method, the used addresses and the stored values will be printed.

I tried to write the following value in order. Please consider that I provided `Data` objects (structs) with the correct `type`.

```
0x11111111 #(type : UINT32)
0x2222222222222222  #(type : UINT64)
0x33  #(type : UINT8)
```

I expected the following output.

```
Memory Address: a,       Value: 11111111
Memory Address: 14,      Value: 2222222222222222
Memory Address: 1e,      Value: 33
Memory dump success
```

But I got this.

```
Memory Address: a,       Value: f7ff2ba011111111
Memory Address: 14,      Value: f7ff2ba022222222
Memory Address: 1e,      Value: f7ff2ba000000033
Memory dump success
```

The first 32 bits are either being overwritten by random values or are not being replaced by the new values I want to write.

I know this is a problem with pointer variables, but can't figure out how to fix this

I tried to figure out if there was any problem with casting by printing the result of casting. That works fine. So the problem is with assigning them into the `values` in the `Memory` struct.

This is the code for testing.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "memory.h"


struct Memory memobj;
struct Memory *mem = &memobj;


int main(){

    uint32_t *addresses[3];
    uint32_t a1=10,a2=20,a3=30;
    addresses[0] = &a1;
    addresses[1] = &a2;
    addresses[2] = &a3;

    uint64_t *values_to_write[3];
    struct Data d1,d2,d3;

    d1.type=UINT32;
    d1.value = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    *(uint32_t*)d1.value=0x11111111;

    d2.type=UINT64;
    d2.value = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    *(uint64_t*)d2.value = 0x222222222222222;

    d3.type=UINT8;
    d3.value = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
    *(uint8_t*)d3.value = 0x33;



    values_to_write[0] = &d1;
    values_to_write[1] = &d2;
    values_to_write[2] = &d3;

    mem->hashtable = (uint32_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    mem->values = (uint64_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    memset(mem->hashtable,0,sizeof(uint32_t)*1);
    memset(mem->values,0,sizeof(uint64_t)*1);
    mem->hashtablesize=0;

    mem->cell_index = cell_index;
    mem->dump = dump;
    mem->extend_hashtable = extend_hashtable;
    mem->read = read;
    mem->write = write;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        mem->write(addresses[i],values_to_write[i],mem);
    }

    mem->dump(mem);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this or where can I find a solution for this?

Comment: `uint64_t **new_values = (uint64_t*)malloc(` You generally should not cast the result of `malloc` and similar functions. Even worse you cast to the wrong type. Does your compiler like it?

Comment: meta note: [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/14193797). You don't have to specify it.

Comment: You allocate memory, clear the memory and then immediately throw the memory away and overwrite it with another pointer `new_hashtable[i] = mem->hashtable[i];`. That causes memory leaks.

Comment: Instead of allocating memory to store different types of values, you could just use a union that holds the correct data types. That will probably not take more memory than the pointer itself does.

Comment: `mem->hashtable = (uint32_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));` Check the sizes you allocate for your pointers.

Comment: I get some 30+ errors/warnings when compiling your code with a standard C compiler. How about compiling your code with a non-broken compiler and fixing those problems first? I recommend using `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @Lundin I use standard c compiler (gcc) for linux

Comment: @KavinduRavishka Apparently not or you wouldn't have 30+ errors. Compile correctly, as shown in my previous comment.